# Returning a file from directory using Java

Tags: java

I have two variables: filename(name of my file), and filePath(path of my file). I concatenated the two to get a complete path,
How can I check a directory and return the specified file based on the full path I created?

```
Filename = element.getChild("FILENAME").getValue();
         String ConcFileName = filePath+Filename;
         File f = new File(ConcFileName);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Paths](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html) class introduced in Java 7  allows you to do just that.

```
Path path = Paths.get("filePath", "FILENAME");
File file = path.toFile();
```

*filePath* is your directory path and *FILENAME* is the actual file name in the directory above

Take a look at the class for other ways to achieve what you want. The code below is more "flexible"

```
Path directory = Paths.get("filePath");
Path path = directory.resolve("filename");
File file = path.toFile();
```

Comment: And a mention of Files might be useful: `Files.createDirectories(directory);` to create possibly non-existing directories.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I check a directory

```
if(f.exists()){
    //file exists
} else {
    //file doesn't exist yet
}
```

> and return the specified file

`f` points to your specified file if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure if your folder is created you can do this:

```
        File f = new File(ConcFileName);
        f.mkdir();
```

f.mkdir() return true if and only if the directory was created; false otherwise